# How can I disable Tap to Click?

Tags: settings, release-juno, touchpad, mouse

how can I disable tap to click on the elementary os? I've tried disabling it from the "Mouse & Touchpad" menu on Settings but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Synaptics touchpad (which I believe is on most laptops), you can use [synclient](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/synclient.1.html) to modify these settings.

To install simply run `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`.

In this case `synclient TapButton1=0` 
should do the trick.

---

You can put this in your `~/.bashrc` to make it permanent.

Refer to the [man page](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/synaptics.4#Tapping) for more options.

Comment: Synclient is not installed by default on my computer, should I install it? or is there an easier way?

Comment: @HasanSuryaman yep it's part of `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` I've updated the answer too.